# Github API Authentication with PUT issues in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, axios, github-api

I am having issues authenticating using the github API with my react-native app. Below is my config I use for axios.

```
  export const AxiosConfig = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
      },
      auth: {
        username: "myusername",
        password: "myauthtoken"
      }
    };
```

Here is the code for the axios call.

```
const URL = `${BASE_USER_URL}/following/${user}`;
console.log(URL);
const newConfig = AxiosConfig;
newConfig["headers"]["Content-Length"] = "0";
await axios
  .put(URL, newConfig)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Followed User");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Could not follow user");
    console.log(error.response.data);
    Alert.alert(
      "Error Trying to Follow User",
      `Could not follow user ${user}`,
      [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }],
      { cancelable: true }
    );
    return;
  });
```

I get the following returned

```
{ "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers
    v3/users/followers/#follow-a-user",
  "message": "Requires authentication",
}
```

But, when I run the same code with .get instead of .put, I get the information back from the get call (which also requires authentication)

In postman, when I call the same URL and use the Authorization UI in postman to set the username/pass, the call works fine.[image]

Whats the issue with my Axios call that it is different than my postman?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with axios.put. To solve I did the following

```
axios({

  method: "put",
  url: URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <token>"
  }
})
```